# Image of formal derivative map on $F[X]$ is $F[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I am self-studying from Fraleigh's book *A First Course in Abstract Algebra* and came across this question.

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and let $D$ be the formal derivative map, so that $D(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots + a_nx^n = a_1 + 2\cdot a_2x + \dots + n \cdot a_nx^{n-1}$.

Find the image of $F[X]$ under $D$.

So, the answer given is that the image is $F[X]$ itself, because $D(\frac{1}{i+1}a_ix^{i+1}) = a_ix^i$ and thus combined with the fact that $D$ is additive and $D(1) = 0$, every polynomial is the derivative of another polynomial in $F[X]$.

Now this makes sense to me, except that $\frac{1}{i+1}$ is not an integer, so how does it make sense to talk about $\frac{1}{i+1}$ times $a_i$?

Fraleigh defined an expression like $n \cdot a$ as $a + a \dots + a$  ($n$ times) for $n$ an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $F$ is a field of characteristic $0$ it contains a canonical copy of $\mathbb{Q}$, and so $\frac{1}{i+1}$ makes sense for any integer $i$ (except for $i=-1$, of course).

More formally, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\tilde{n} = 1+1+\cdots+1$ ($n$ times).  Then $\tilde{n} \in F$, and because the characteristic of $F$ is $0$ we have $\tilde{n} \neq 0$.  Since $F$ is a field, it follows that there is a multiplicative inverse for $\tilde{n}$ in $F$, which we denote $1/\tilde{n}$.  It's then conventional to just write $n$ instead of $\tilde{n}$, so $\frac{1}{n}$ now makes sense as an element of $F$.

Comment: Thanks. I see now that Fraleigh discusses this further in the text.